# Plot common elements of categorical data between the groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I have my data that looks like this (actual data has 4000 rows):

```
tt <- structure(list(X = c("k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Pezizomycotina_cls_Incertae_sedis;o__Pezizomycotina_ord_Incertae_sedis;f__Pezizomycotina_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Vermispora", 
"k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Saccharomycetes;o__Saccharomycetales;f__Saccharomycetales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Candida", 
"k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Sordariomycetes;o__Branch06;f__unidentified;g__unidentified", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Betaproteobacteria;o__Burkholderiales;f__Oxalobacteraceae;g__Massilia", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Actinobacteria;o__Actinomycetales;f__Pseudonocardiaceae;g__Amycolatopsis", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Armatimonadetes;c__Armatimonadia;o__FW68;f__;g__", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Deltaproteobacteria;o__Syntrophobacterales;f__Syntrophobacteraceae;g__", 
"k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Pleosporales;f__Leptosphaeriaceae;g__Leptosphaeria", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__WPS-2;D_2__metagenome;D_3__metagenome;D_4__metagenome;D_5__metagenome", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Patescibacteria;D_2__Saccharimonadia;D_3__Saccharimonadales;D_4__Saccharimonadaceae;D_5__Candidatus Saccharibacteria bacterium RAAC3_TM7_1", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Chloroflexi;D_2__AD3;D_3__uncultured bacterium;D_4__uncultured bacterium;D_5__uncultured bacterium", 
"k__Fungi;p__Chytridiomycota;c__Chytridiomycetes;o__Rhizophydiales;f__Rhizophydiales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Coralloidiomyces", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidetes;c__Cytophagia;o__Cytophagales;f__Cytophagaceae;g__Pontibacter", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__WS2;D_2__uncultured soil bacterium;D_3__uncultured soil bacterium;D_4__uncultured soil bacterium;D_5__uncultured soil bacterium", 
"k__Fungi;p__Basidiomycota;c__Agaricomycetes;o__Thelephorales;f__Thelephoraceae;g__Amaurodon", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Patescibacteria;D_2__Parcubacteria;D_3__Candidatus Kaiserbacteria;D_4__metagenome;D_5__metagenome", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Betaproteobacteria;o__Burkholderiales;f__Oxalobacteraceae;g__Janthinobacterium", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidetes;c__Bacteroidia;o__Bacteroidales;__;__", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Bacteroidetes;D_2__Bacteroidia;D_3__Sphingobacteriales;D_4__Sphingobacteriaceae;D_5__Pedobacter", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Acidobacteriia;o__Acidobacteriales;f__Koribacteraceae;g__", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Planctomycetes;D_2__Planctomycetacia;D_3__Pirellulales;D_4__Pirellulaceae;D_5__Pirellula", 
"k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Pezizomycetes;o__Pezizales;f__Sarcosomataceae;g__Urnula", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Proteobacteria;D_2__Alphaproteobacteria;D_3__Azospirillales;D_4__uncultured;D_5__uncultured bacterium", 
"k__Fungi;p__Basidiomycota;c__Agaricomycetes;o__Polyporales;f__Meruliaceae;g__Uncobasidium", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Dependentiae;D_2__Babeliae;D_3__Babeliales;D_4__Vermiphilaceae;__", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Proteobacteria;D_2__Alphaproteobacteria;D_3__Caulobacterales;D_4__Caulobacteraceae;D_5__Caulobacter", 
"k__Fungi;p__Mortierellomycota;__;__;__;__", "k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Pleosporales;f__Dictyosporiaceae;g__Dictyosporium", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__;o__;f__;g__", "D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Patescibacteria;D_2__Gracilibacteria;D_3__Absconditabacteriales (SR1);__;__", 
"k__Fungi;p__Basidiomycota;c__Agaricomycetes;o__Agaricales;f__Entolomataceae;g__Clitopilus", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Betaproteobacteria;o__Burkholderiales;f__Burkholderiaceae;g__", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Armatimonadetes;D_2__Fimbriimonadia;D_3__Fimbriimonadales;D_4__Fimbriimonadaceae;D_5__Armatimonadetes bacterium 55-13", 
"k__Fungi;p__Basidiomycota;c__Agaricomycetes;o__Agaricales;f__Bolbitiaceae;g__Agrocybe", 
"k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Leotiomycetes;o__Helotiales;f__Helotiales_fam_Incertae_sedis;__", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Cyanobacteria;D_2__Oxyphotobacteria;D_3__Oxyphotobacteria Incertae Sedis;D_4__Unknown Family;D_5__Leptolyngbya ANT.L52.2", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Chloroflexi;c__Chloroflexi;o__[Roseiflexales];f__[Kouleothrixaceae];__", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Proteobacteria;D_2__Alphaproteobacteria;D_3__Rhizobiales;D_4__Hyphomicrobiaceae;__", 
"k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Eurotiomycetes;o__Onygenales;f__Onygenales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Spiromastix", 
"k__Fungi;p__Basidiomycota;c__Tremellomycetes;o__Tremellales;f__Bulleribasidiaceae;g__Vishniacozyma", 
"k__Fungi;p__Basidiomycota;c__Tremellomycetes;o__Tremellales;f__Bulleribasidiaceae;g__Bulleribasidium", 
"k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Pleosporales;f__Corynesporascaceae;g__Corynespora", 
"k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Eurotiomycetes;o__Chaetothyriales;f__Cyphellophoraceae;g__Cyphellophora", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Gammaproteobacteria;o__Xanthomonadales;f__Sinobacteraceae;__", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Proteobacteria;D_2__Deltaproteobacteria;D_3__SAR324 clade(Marine group B);__;__", 
"k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Leotiomycetes;o__Leotiomycetes_ord_Incertae_sedis;f__Myxotrichaceae;g__Oidiodendron", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Deltaproteobacteria;o__Myxococcales;f__Cystobacteraceae;g__Cystobacter", 
"D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Patescibacteria;D_2__Parcubacteria;D_3__Candidatus Kaiserbacteria;D_4__uncultured bacterium;D_5__uncultured bacterium", 
"k__Fungi;p__Chytridiomycota;c__Spizellomycetes;o__Spizellomycetales;f__Spizellomycetaceae;g__Spizellomyces", 
"k__Bacteria;p__Armatimonadetes;c__Chthonomonadetes;o__SJA-22;f__;g__"
), Reject.null.hypothesis = c("False", "False", "False", "False", 
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", 
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", 
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", 
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", 
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", 
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", 
"False", "False", "False", "False"), W = c(3L, 57L, 89L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 6L, 33L, 27L, 28L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 1L, 
15L, 26L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 15L, 0L, 23L, 6L, 1L, 45L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 45L, 3L, 7L, 192L, 53L, 0L, 2L, 8L, 0L, 18L, 
7L, 0L), Type = structure(c(4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 
7L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 
9L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 2L), .Label = c("Soil_16S_Monmouth_ancom.csv", 
"Soil_16S_Urbana_ancom.csv", "Soil_ITS_Monmouth_ancom.csv", "Soil_ITS_urbana_ancom.csv", 
"Rhizoshpere_16S_U_and_M_together_ancom.tsv", "Rhizoshpere_ITS_U_and_M_together_ancom.tsv", 
"Rhizoshpere_16S_Monmouth_only_ancom.tsv", "Rhizoshpere_16S_Urbana_only_ancom.tsv", 
"Rhizoshpere_ITS_Monmouth_only_ancom.tsv", "Rhizoshpere_ITS_Urbana_only_ancom.tsv"
), class = "factor"), microbiome_type = c("Soil", "Rhizosphere", 
"Rhizosphere", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Rhizosphere", 
"Rhizosphere", "Rhizosphere", "Rhizosphere", "Soil", "Soil", 
"Rhizosphere", "Soil", "Rhizosphere", "Soil", "Soil", "Rhizosphere", 
"Soil", "Rhizosphere", "Soil", "Rhizosphere", "Rhizosphere", 
"Rhizosphere", "Rhizosphere", "Rhizosphere", "Rhizosphere", "Soil", 
"Rhizosphere", "Rhizosphere", "Soil", "Rhizosphere", "Rhizosphere", 
"Soil", "Rhizosphere", "Soil", "Rhizosphere", "Rhizosphere", 
"Rhizosphere", "Rhizosphere", "Soil", "Rhizosphere", "Soil", 
"Rhizosphere", "Soil", "Soil", "Rhizosphere", "Rhizosphere", 
"Soil")), row.names = c(3771L, 3792L, 3806L, 2839L, 1913L, 2004L, 
2956L, 3311L, 1619L, 1008L, 535L, 4785L, 2087L, 1625L, 4564L, 
977L, 2836L, 2059L, 510L, 1706L, 1090L, 3750L, 1143L, 4514L, 
848L, 1158L, 4873L, 3268L, 1658L, 952L, 4299L, 2792L, 408L, 4279L, 
3610L, 827L, 2217L, 1275L, 3573L, 4713L, 4704L, 3258L, 3499L, 
3018L, 1487L, 3668L, 2913L, 982L, 4806L, 2013L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot `X` against `microbiome_type` to show common `X` present in `Soil` and `Rhizoshphere`. Meaning, I want to see which bacteria and fungal communities (from column `X`) are shared (as well as not-shared) between Rhizosphere and Soil `microbiome_type`.

I tried something like this below, but it is not giving me what I want:

```
ggplot(tt, aes(microbiome_type, X)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = Type), size = 0.9)+
  ggpubr::color_palette("jco")+
  ggpubr::theme_pubclean() +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~Reject.null.hypothesis)
```

Can someone please suggest me a better way to plot this type of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't work in microbiology, so I don't know what the exact level of analysis should be here to answer your question properly. However, it does seem to me that the way your data is structured now, is ill-equipped to answer your question. For example, I expect that some fungal and bacterial species to occur more than once in `X`, but `X` is a factor describing a particular community of micro-organisms, wherein membership-level information is lost because it is encoded in the factor level.

My suggestion is then, to split up `X` into individual taxa and for those taxa, visualise whether they are found in the soil or the rhizosphere.

```
new_x <- strsplit(tt$X, ";")

# Recombine with original information, you might get a warning about rownames
newdat <- lapply(seq_along(new_x), function(i) {
  cbind(X = new_x[[i]], tt[i,-1])
})
newdat <- do.call(rbind, newdat)

ggplot(newdat, aes(microbiome_type, X, group = X)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Type)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ Reject.null.hypothesis)
```

[image]

Now it is easy to spot what species is both in the soil and in the rhizosphere.